# Unable to insert data in cassandra-cli

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

Getting

```
 cassandra  error: cannot parse uuid as hex bytes` 

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: cannot parse '8768c481-a118-48b7-aed2-2903b917d045' as hex bytes
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.doExecute(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.execute(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:191)
    at CassClass.main(CassClass.java:55)
```

Schema:

```
{
  column_name: key, 
  validation_class: UTF8Type, 
  index_type: KEYS
}  where key is UUID generated 
as UUID key = UUIDGenerator.getInstance().generateRandomBasedUUID();
```

CLI Commands:

```
// Created column family with:
create column family newdata with comparator = UTF8Type;

// Then, updated the column family newdata with:
column_metadata =[{column_name: key, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}];
```

Comment: Can you paste your whole cassandra-cli output?  What is your schema?

Comment: {column_name: key, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS} where key is UUID generated as UUID key = UUIDGenerator.getInstance().generateRandomBasedUUID();

Comment: What cassandra-cli command are you using?

Comment: Created column family with <i>create column family newdata with comparator = UTF8Type;</i>
then,
update column family newdata with column_metadata =[{column_name: key, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}];

Comment: inserting through data through with cqlsh command INSERT INTO newdata (key) VALUES ('8768c481-a118-48b7-aed2-2903b917d045');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CQL, it is best practice to create your column families with CQL too.  It seems you've found a bug, since the resulting CQL schema is invalid (there are two columns called key):

```
CREATE TABLE newdata (
  key blob PRIMARY KEY,
  key text
);
```

However, if you want just one field that is indexed, you probably want the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE newdata (
  key uuid PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Here, the primary key is of type UUID so a check is done that your key is a valid UUID.  You can then insert with:

```
INSERT INTO newdata (key) VALUES (8768c481-a118-48b7-aed2-2903b917d045);
```

Then you can do lookups like:

```
SELECT * FROM newdata1 where key = 8768c481-a118-48b7-aed2-2903b917d045;
```

which will tell you if the UUID exists or not.  You can add other columns later and retrieve them with the above SELECT query.